# Microsoft Text Encodings

Tags: vb.net, ascii

Have a string being returned from a modem as such;

TÁÎË ÐROÄÕCT             ÖOLÕÍE TC ÖOLÕÍE   ÕLLÁÇE   ÈEIÇÈT    WÁTER     TEÍÐ

When I save the text to a document and open it in Word I am able to decode it using the "US-ASCII" encoding and get the follwing text.

TANK PRODUCT             VOLUME TC VOLUME   ULLAGE   HEIGHT    WATER     TEMP

However for the life of me I cannot figure out how to acheive the same results in vb. Am using  Visual Basic Express 2010.

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Show the VB code that you are trying to use.

Comment: Also, where exactly are you viewing it that it is showing up with the incorrect encoding?

Comment: Looks like parity bits being set, and then stripped... Probably not exactly an encoding issue.

Comment: Make sure that the settings on the serial port are correct, I'd guess 9600-8-N-1.  The default encoding for the port is ASCII I believe.

Comment: @dbasnett: Good point.  I was wondering why the two versions had so many similarities.  That is probably what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out it wasn't an encoding issue as you all pointed out but rather the word length and parity both needed to be adjusted. Final settings on the modem ended up being 9600-7-Odd-1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Turns out it wasn't an encoding issue as you all pointed out but rather the word length and parity both needed to be adjusted. Final settings on the modem ended up being 9600-7-Odd-1.